# Code for how to make an image gallery in android

Tags: android, xml, image

i am new to android and i dont know how to code image gallery.

i have been given many images and i have to build an image gallery for an app which i am developing how to build an app i have saved all the images onto drawable-hdpi folder

now i have created one xml file in which there is a button as image gallery
when i click this image it has to go to other xml file and display the first image then if i swipe all the images one by one has to populate such that i can swipe all the images

[image]

pls write the code below such that i can swipe all the images which are in drawable folder 
and also the xml file what i have to modify

rajshree sister and androidgeek waiting for u both pls help me

Comment: please give me the code it is urgent or else i will land onto problem

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We don't just "write the code below". [Here's some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question.

Comment: @keyboardsurfer sorry yaar .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer the link http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/ and search for gridview examples.

Comment: but there no image swiping yaar should we use scroll view to view it

Comment: hey shriram can u check this code if u r free http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241999/android-media-player-url-is-not-set-properly?noredirect=1#comment35561897_23241999 @Shriram